# Anywhere Digital Signature Feature Issue

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am working on Anywhere development, Is it possible to use the Real and electronic signature features in current code base version 7.5.2.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's only available in 7.6 and higher releases.